# Sidebar is extending past viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a [website](https://jsfiddle.net/abustamam/80qwvf7L/2/embedded/result/) where I want a header and a sidebar.

My intended functionality is that the sidebar extends to the bottom of the page, which it does. However, it has content that extends beyond the viewport, I'm guessing because the `.menu` is sized to 100% of the entire body container, yet is pushed down because of the header.

How do I make it such that the menu only extends all the way down the viewport?

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <header class='row'>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <a href="#" class="menu-icon-link">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
          </span>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="row menu-container">
        <div class="menu col-md-2">
            Lorem ipsum...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

My CSS:

```
html, body{ 
  height: 100%; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative; 
  padding: 3.5em 0 0 0; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-container {
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #A9E2AD;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.glyphicon-list {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #FFF;
} 

header {
    background: #50af4c;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use an explicit height, you can use positioning for what you want.

```
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3.5em;
  bottom: 0; //add this
  padding: 1em;
  background: #A9E2AD;
  //height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Worked like a charm.